# Sending Float Data Type from Arduino to ESP32 (NodeMCU)

Tags: arduino, nodemcu, esp32

I am trying to have a NodeMCU(ESP32) receive a floating data type from an Arduino Uno but I do not have any idea how. Can someone please guide me through the process? For now, I have the basic serial communication code sending a single digit Int from the Arduino to the NodeMCU.

---

Sender (Arduino Uno):

```cpp
int val = 1;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(19200); 
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.write(val);
  delay(3000);
}
```

---

Receiver (NodeMCU):

```cpp
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
HardwareSerial receiver(2);

void setup() 
{
  receiver.begin(19200, SERIAL_8N1, 16, 17); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  if(receiver.available() > 0)
  {
    int received = receiver.read();
    Serial.println(received); //tried printing the result to the serial monitor
  }
  delay(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write/read in the form you use it, is for single bytes only. A float in Arduino consists of 4 bytes.
You can use write to send a series of bytes, and you have to read those bytes, arriving one after the other, depending on the serial speed. Synchronization/lost bytes might be a problem, here in this simple solution I assume the best.

Sender:

```
float val = 1.234;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200); 
}

void loop() {
  Serial.write((byte*)&val,4);
  delay(3000);
}
```

Receiver:

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
HardwareSerial receiver(2);

void setup() 
{
  receiver.begin(19200, SERIAL_8N1, 16, 17); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() 
{
  if(receiver.available() > 0)
  {
     delay(5);  // wait for all 4 bytes
     byte buf[4];
     byte* bp = buf;
     while (receiver.available()) {
        *bp = receiver.read();
        if (bp - buf < 3) bp++;
     }  
     float received = * (float*)buf;
     Serial.println(received, 3); // printing the result to the serial monitor
  }
  delay(100); // not really required, should be smaller than sender cycle
}
```